# prolog uncaught exception error

Tags: prolog

Hi I'm new to prolog and I was trying to create a basic family tree so fair i have this:

```
/* Database for family. It consists of facts and rules. */

/* Facts */
female(ella).
female(jodi). 
female(sonya).
male(arnold).
male(chris).
male(louis).
male(mark).
father_of(arnold, chris). /* arnold is the father of chris */
father_of(louis, mark).
father_of(mark, arnold).    
mother_of(ella, sonya).
mother_of(jodi, ella).
mother_of(jodi, mark).

/* Rules */
grandmother_of(X, Z) :- 
    mother_of(X, Y), 
    (mother_of(Y, Z); father_of(Y, Z)).

familyquestions :-      
grandmother_of(X, arnold),
write('The grandmother of Arnold is '), write(X), nl,
father_of(Y, mark),
write(Y), write(' is the father of Mark'), nl, nl.
```

However, I was trying to do this:
Define (Add into the database) a rule called is_male(X) that returns "yes" (or "true") if X is the father of somebody.
Note, the system will return a "yes", if it finds a "true" answer and there exist no more true answers. The system will return "true ?" if it finds a "true" answer and there are still possibly further matches. In 
this case, if you type "enter", it will return "yes" and stop. If you type ";", it will continue to search for further answers.
1.2 Define a rule called is_female(X) that returns "yes" or "true" if X is the mother of somebody.
1.3 Remove (comment out) the facts that are not essential (have been covered by the new rules is_male/1 and is_female/1) you have added to the database.

So I added this

/* Database for family. It consists of facts and rules. */

```
/* Facts */
female(ella).
female(jodi). 
female(sonya).
male(arnold).
male(chris).
male(louis).
male(mark).
father_of(arnold, chris). /* arnold is the father of chris */
father_of(louis, mark).
father_of(mark, arnold).    
mother_of(ella, sonya).
mother_of(jodi, ella).
mother_of(jodi, mark).

/* Rules */
grandmother_of(X, Z) :- 
    mother_of(X, Y), 
    (mother_of(Y, Z); father_of(Y, Z)).

 is_male(X, Y) :-
        father_of(X, Y).

 is_female(X, Y) :-
          mother_of(X, Y).

familyquestions :-      
grandmother_of(X, arnold),
write('The grandmother of Arnold is '), write(X), nl,
father_of(Y, mark),
write(Y), write(' is the father of Mark'), nl, nl.
```

but when i ran it, it gave me this code:
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,is_male/1),top_level/0)

Answer (score 3):

The error `error(existence_error(procedure,is_male/1),top_level/0)` says that you are calling a unary predicate `is_male`, i.e. that you are calling `is_male(X)` or something like that. But you defined only a binary predicate `is_male` (the arity of predicates is indicated by appending `/N` to the name of the `N`-ary predicate).

Perhaps you want to define `is_male` as:

```
is_male(X) :- father_of(X, _).
```

Beware that this rule is **not sufficient**.
You may want to extend it, because there can be persons in your KB which are male, but are not father of someone else.

Once you completed the definition of `is_male/1`, you can determine the sex of a person `p` by calling `is_male(p)` instead of checking the fact `male(p)`.
There are some persons for which the fact `male(p)` is redundant, because they are also fathers of someone else. You should remove those redundant facts as asked.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! and yeah i understand now where i was going wrong.